# Linux guest under VMWare - Literally HUGE fonts in some applications and situations

Tags: windows-7, linux, xorg, vmware-workstation

So I have installed a Linux guest (Ubuntu 12.04 alternate with expert install), for development. (Easier than keeping around cygwin and stuff.)

But it happens, that some windows come up with *huge* fonts. Check the image for reference. I have no idea what may cause this behaviour. I have already run "obconf", KDE's "systemsettings", and so on. But nothing. NOTE: This previously already happened under VMWare guests (linux).

[image]

Host: Windows 7 x64 SP1
Guest: Ubuntu 12.04 alternate, with expert install (xorg, kde, openbox)
VMWare: Workstation 8.0.2 - vmware-tools installed

**Update no.1**: Seems like it's only happening after setting the display size with `xrandr` by hand, after logging in.

**Update no.2**: Tried writing a Xorg.conf ([can be read here](http://pastebin.com/ZjuHkK44)), but Ubuntu ignored it right at reboot. (It's located in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: The display size was set to 1920x1080 with xrandr (manually), and I have installed "vmware-tools" from the disc already.

Comment: This may be a bug in Ubuntu(xorg-server): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/969154